# How to check if user has granted permission from outside an activity/fragment in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I am using dexter to provide runtime permission with navigation component.

I have a single activity with multiple fragments.

In the activity, I want to ask the user to grant permission (storage).

Then I have a class (Not Activity or Fragment) that needs to check if the user has granted permission before accessing some codes that require runtime Permission..

I also have a viewModel that runs code that will require runtime permission

**Problem**

I cant access context in any of these classes/viewModel. How do I now check if the user has granted permission or not.

**Utility Class**

```
fun requestExternalStoragePermission(context: Context, callback: PermissionsCallback) {
    Dexter.withContext(context) //
        .withPermissions(listOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
            override fun onPermissionsChecked(p0: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                p0?.let {
                    if (p0.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        callback.onPermissionRequest(granted = true)
                    } else {
                        callback.onPermissionRequest(granted = false)
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                p0: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                p1: PermissionToken?
            ) {
                p1?.continuePermissionRequest()
            }
        })
        .check()
}
```

**Interface**

```
 interface PermissionsCallback {
  fun onPermissionRequest(granted: Boolean)
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    checkForPermission()
    setContentView(binding.root)
}

 private fun checkForPermission(){
  Utility.requestExternalStoragePermission(
      this,
      object : PermissionsCallback {
      override fun onPermissionRequest(granted: Boolean) {
      if (granted) {
       //good
       } else {
       //show settings
     }
}
```

**UPDATED**

**MusicService**

```
class MusicService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {

 private val serviceJob = Job()
 private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + 
serviceJob)

var context: Context? = null
   
    override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    context = this
    checkForPermission()
  
 }

  private fun checkForPermission(){
    Utility.requestExternalStoragePermission(
        this,
        object : PermissionsCallback {
            override fun onPermissionRequest(granted: Boolean) {
                if (granted) {
                    //good, load songs
                    serviceScope.launch {
                        musicSource.fetchMediaData()
                    }
                } else {
                    //do something else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "We need permission nowwww", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }
        })
 }

 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    serviceScope.cancel()

    exoPlayer.removeListener(musicPlayerEventListener)
    exoPlayer.release()

}

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
 init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val allArtistes = artisteDatabase.getAllArtiste().....//I need to check here tooo
        _artisteList.value = Resource.success(allArtistes)
    }
}

fun doGetArtisteSongs(long: Long){
    viewModelScope.launch {
         val artisteSongs = artisteDatabase.getArtisteSongs(long).....//I need to check here too
        _artisteSongList.value = Resource.success(artisteSongs)
    }
}
```

I wouldnt be able to use my Utility function to check for permission on that non-activiy/fragment class and viewmodel because it requires a 'context'.

Whats the proper way out?

Comment: I could see you have a function in your utility class and has a parameter of context, and passing from activity, what is the error?

Comment: No error... I want to check if same permission has been granted in a non-activity/fragment class and a viewModel (Which has no context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MusicService is service class you can get context from service.

```
 Context context;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
    }
    
 //then you can call requestExternalStoragePermission() using context.

 //If you want context in viewmodel use HILT dependency injection library.

 @ViewModelInject
    public MainViewModel(MainRepository mainRepository, @ApplicationContext Context context) {
        this.repository = mainRepository;
        this.context = context;

    }
```

Comment: This works...thanks but I have an issue.

When user clicks grant permission from MainActivity (Normally app loads list of songs immediately)...But right now, I have to close the app and re-open before the songs appear (From MusicService class)

Comment: no need to close and reopen app.In MainActivity call your checkForPermission() with in onStart().@Ibramazin

Comment: I did that, not working. The thing is in MainActivity, if the permission has been granted...I am not doing anything.

I am writing thesame code to check in (MusicService) but in there if granted -> (Then serviceScope.launch { musicSource.fetchMediaData() } ) //fetch songs...

Comment: can you show all the code in MusicService?@Ibramazin

Comment: sure, check updated MusicService class.

I tried to apply same logic from MainActivity -> If granted -> serviceScope.launch{                        musicSource.fetchMediaData()} but songs not appearing If I use MainActivity

Comment: i believe nothing wrong and i am not familiar in kotlin.so please double check this line of code serviceScope.launch {}.sorry @Ibramazin